# How to check this If Condition? - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have variable number of input values. 
Like input is an array with variable values like [6,23,6] or [8,3,97].. like that and also i need to check it against another array.
Hence, I form a condition like this,

```
StringBuilder formStmt= new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

                formStmt= formStmt.append("input[" + i + "] != anotherArray[" +i+ "] &&");
            }
            formStmt= formStmt.delete(formStmt.length()-2, formStmt.length());
```

How to check **formStmt** inside if?

The Thing is I'm forming the if statement using formStmt. I'm forming

```
formStmt = input[0] !=anotherArray[i] && input[1] != anotherArray[i]
```

and placing it inside if.. like

```
if (formStmt){
```

//code
}

Edit:
I have updated the question. The right side value also is an array. Thats why I go for a stmt like this.?

Comment: What is the condition you want to check?

Comment: what you need to check... please explain it breifly

Comment: I think you need to understand some more basics of programming. Because an if must always contain a boolean and your `if(formStmt)` contains a StringBuilder. You can't create an if-statement inside a String/StringBuilder and put that String/StringBuilder inside the if..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I understand, you want to check every input[i]'s value against 0. try this :

```
bool status=true;

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

   if(input[i] == 0)
   {
       status=false;
       break;
   }
}

if(status)
{  // do  your stuff}
```

so according to your updated question, you will need a nested loop. something like this :

```
bool status=true;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length && status; i++) 
{
   for(j = 0; j < anotherArray.length; j++)
   {
       if(input[i] == anotherArray[j])
       {
           status=false;
           break; // you can use a labeled break if you want
       }
}

if(status)
{  // do  your stuff}
```

Comment: I have given here as 0 but the value right to == also changes. In such case how to use?

Comment: then it depends. if the RHS value changes uniformly with a pattern or randomly

Comment: both are user inputs.. but just the number of inputs varies.. input array and anotherArray are same size always.

Comment: then use if(input[i]==anotherArray[i]). If this is not it, then please give a clearer picture of your problem.

Comment: updated the answer. may be this is what you wanted or atleast that is what I think you wanted. If it helps, then glad it helped (don't forget to mark it as answer if you find it useful). If it doesn't then you should ask you Programming instructor. May be you will be able to present your problem more accurately face to face :)

Comment: Thanks.. Yeah.. Almost like this.. Solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't build up code in a String.

You want to check that all of the elements of the Collection are non-zero.

```
boolean valid = true;
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if (input.get(i) == 0) {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```